# Expo AV React Native Local Sound File issue

Tags: react-native, audio, expo-av

I am trying to create an audio player with react native and expo av. I can play online remote files (through uri) just fine, and my code works well. However, whenever I attempt to play a local file, it throws the error: `[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Cannot load an AV asset from a null playback source]`. Most of my code for audio handling right now is dealt with through `handleAudioPlayPause`, which gets called on a button press. How can I get this program to play local files without an issue? Thanks

```
const audio = {
  filename: 'Audio file 1',
  uri:
  require('../assets/sounds/hello.mp3'), //this does not work
    // 'https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba.mp3', // this works
};
```

...

```
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
const [playbackObject, setPlaybackObject] = useState<any | null>(null);
const [playbackStatus, setPlaybackStatus] = useState<any | null>(null);
useEffect(() => {
    if (playbackObject === null) {
      setPlaybackObject(new Audio.Sound());
    }
  }, []);
   const handleAudioPlayPause = async () => {
    if (playbackObject !== null && playbackStatus === null) {
      const status = await playbackObject.loadAsync(
        { uri: audio.uri },
        { shouldPlay: true }
      );
      setIsPlaying(true);
      return setPlaybackStatus(status);
    }

    // It will pause our audio
    if (playbackStatus.isPlaying) {
      const status = await playbackObject.pauseAsync();
      setIsPlaying(false);
      return setPlaybackStatus(status);
    }

    // It will resume our audio
    if (!playbackStatus.isPlaying) {
      const status = await playbackObject.playAsync();
      console.log(status);
      setIsPlaying(true);
      return setPlaybackStatus(status);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See there are different ways to load an audio file

1. For remote Files use it as you were doing

```
const status = await playbackObject.loadAsync(
  { uri: audio.uri }, // For remote files we have to place uri like this
  { shouldPlay: true }
);
```

2. But for local files, you have to use it like this,

```
const status = await playbackObject.loadAsync(
  audio.uri, // For local files we have to use it like this
  { shouldPlay: true }
);
```

[Working Example here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/remote-and-local-sounds)

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of  `useState` you should have used `useRef`, because useState causes rerender but useRef does not. We usually use `useState` if we want to reflect the change on UI.

```
  const soundRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
       #you could have multiple sound files to load
        const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();
  
        const loadSounds = async () => {
            await soundObject.loadAsync("Your config");
            soundRef.current = soundObject;

        };
        loadSounds();
        // ALways clean up running files
        return () => {
            soundObject && soundObject.unloadAsync();
            
        };
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to improve Kartikey answer, for a local file the following worked for me.

```
 const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
  { uri: recording.getURI() },
  {
    shouldPlay: true,
  }
);
```